# What does !$ mean?

Tags: bash, command-history

I'm following through a tutorial and it mentions to run this command:

```
sudo chmod 700 !$
```

I'm not familiar with `!$`. What does it mean?

Comment: It's generally safe to try to `echo` something if you're not sure what it'll do.

Comment: @Shadur, not always.  `echo $(rm -rf /)`

Comment: @cjm Unless you're on a really old system, you'll need the `--no-preserve-root` option in there, and if you see the words "no preserve" in a program you better think real carefully about what it does.

Comment: @WChargin Be very careful assuming that "really old" and "not Linux/not using GNU coreutils" are the same thing; they aren't.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Basically, it's the last argument to the previous command.

> `!$` is the "end" of the previous command. Consider the following
>   example: We start by looking for a word in a file:
>
> ```
> grep -i joe /some/long/directory/structure/user-lists/list-15
> ```
>
> if joe is in that userlist, we want to remove him from it. We can either fire up vi with that long directory tree as the argument, or as simply as `vi !$` Which
>   bash expands to:
>
> ```
> vi /some/long/directory/structure/user-lists/list-15
> ```

<sup>([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20130901181242/http://deadman.org/bash.php); handy guide, by the way)</sup>

---

It's worth nothing the distinction between this `!$` token and the special shell variable `$_`.
Indeed, *both* expand to the last argument of the previous command. However, `!$` is expanded during *history expansion*, while `$_` is expanded during *parameter expansion*.
One important consequence of this is that, when you use `!$`, the *expanded* command is saved in your history.

For example, consider the keystrokes

- `echo Foo` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `echo !$ Jar` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>; and
- `echo Foo` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `echo $_ Jar` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

(The only characters changed are the `$!` and `$_` in the middle.)

In the former, when you press <kbd>Up</kbd>, the command line reads `echo Foo Jar`, so the last line written to stdout is `Foo Jar`.

In the latter, when you press <kbd>Up</kbd>, the command line reads `echo $_ bar`, but now `$_` has a different value than it did previously—indeed, `$_` is now `Jar`, so the last line written to stdout is `Jar Jar`.

Another consequence is that `_` can be used in other parameter expansions, for example, the sequence of commands

```
printf '%s '    isomorphism
printf '%s\n'   ${_%morphism}sceles
```

prints `isomorphism isosceles`.
But there's no analogous "`${!$%morphism}`" expansion.

For more information about the phases of expansion in Bash, see the `EXPANSION` section of `man 1 bash` (this is called [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) in the online edition). The `HISTORY EXPANSION` section is separate.

Comment: Nice. Good to know. Also, good thing there's Stack Exchange. It's hard to search Google for something like `!$`

Comment: BTW, on the command line, you can insert the last argument of the previous command by `insert-last-argument`, usually bound to `M-.`.

Comment: @Andrew please remember to accept this if it answers your question. Accepting and upvoting rather than posting comments are how thanks are expressed on the SE network, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180/203101) for the "official" stance.

Comment: @Andrew FYI, I searched Google for "bash bang dollar" and got decent results, including this link as the third listing.

Comment: @terdon I tried to accept the answer last night, but it was so fast that I was forced to wait to accept it.

Comment: *(The only characters changed are the `$!` and `$_` in the middle)*. I guess you meant `!$` instead of `$!`

Comment: *prints `isomorphism isosceles`*. No, it prints `isosceles`

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut In fact, the sequence of two commands listed above does print `isomorphism isosceles`. Note that the running text reads, "the **sequence of commands** `[...]` prints…".

Comment: @Andrew: this page was the first result to Googling "What does !$ do in Linux?"

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking `!$` is the last word of the last command from the history list.

> word - A sequence of characters treated as a unit by the shell. Words may not include unquoted metacharacters.
>
> metacharacter - A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a blank or one of the following characters: ‘|’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘(’, ‘)’, ‘<’, or ‘>’
>
> blank - A space or tab character.

**Examples:**

```
set -o history # enable command history
set -o histexpand # enable ! style history substitution

HISTSIZE=10

# save all lines on the history list    
HISTCONTROL=
HISTIGNORE=

date
echo !$ # prints date

date>/dev/null
echo !$ # prints /dev/null

echo a b c>/dev/null
echo !$ # prints /dev/null

HISTCONTROL=ignorespace # lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list
echo a b c
 echo d e f # space at the beginning
echo !$ # prints c
```

Comment: see also: [Bash and its exclamation mark command, preview actual command before executing it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206698/bash-and-its-exclamation-mark-command-preview-actual-command-before-executing-i/210943#210943)

Answer (score -3):

`!$` will give you last command used for that particular user....

you can also find the history of commands used earlier by using `history` command... try it out....

NOTE: For a particular user, all the commands used earlier will be stored under bash history file.

Comment: The other answers are right.  This one is wrong.