# Bash and its exclamation mark command, preview actual command before executing it?

Tags: bash, command-history

`!` as a prefix to some string will execute whatever command in the command buffer that starts with the (partial) string given. There are also some other uses for it. See e.g. [Understanding the exclamation mark (!) in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash)

My question is, how can I preview what command will be executed before executing it? E.g. if I do `!for`, and I've written several commands starting with 'for' previously, but I'm not completely sure if the one I think was the last one is indeed the one I think. It would be very useful if bash could show me what the command that would be executed is before I actually execute it. Is there any way to do this in bash?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in an answer that does not involve using a completely different approach (e.g. using vi mode).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4079/put-history-command-onto-command-line-without-executing-it/

Answer (score 5):

Bash has inherited the `!` mechanism from `csh`.  The way to preview your command in both shells is to add a `:p` to the end.

```
!for:p
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `histverify` shell option:

```
histverify
    If set, and readline is being used, the results of history substitution
    are not immediately passed to the shell parser.  Instead,
    the resulting line is loaded into the readline editing buffer,
    allowing further modification.
```

Example:

```
$ shopt -s histverify
$ !shopt
```

Another useful option is `histreedit`:

```
histreedit
    If set, and readline is being used, a user is given the opportunity
    to re-edit a failed history substitution.
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually abstain from (IMO broken) `!` substitution and use the shell history functions instead; e.g. in *vi-mode* (you will certainly find equivalent options in *emacs-mode*) you'd search for the last occurrence, with your example that would be `<Esc>` `/` `for` `<Enter>`, and (if it's not the command you wanted) repeat search for the next appearance of `for` using the key `n` (or `N` to go in the other direction), and confirm the desired command with `<Enter>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can map `readline` commands `history-search-backward` and `history-search-forward` to something (I'm using <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd>) and use them to navigate through history instead of `!`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `vi` mode (`set -o vi`) hit `Esc` or `C-[` and `k` or `UP` to go up in history and `j` or `DOWN` to go down.
You can edit what you've arrived at or execute it with `Enter`.