# shell command cd !$

Tags: command-line, terminal

I looked at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67/74155) and googled, but can't find a definitive answer. What does `!$` do when typed into terminal?

I typed

```
mkdir /path/to/dir
cd !$
```

Which brought me to `/path/to/dir` but I still would like to know exactly what the `!$` operator does in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From  Bash Manual > History Expansion:

- Event Designator

  ```
  !      Start a history substitution, except when followed by 
         a blank, newline, carriage return, = or  (  (when the 
         extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin).
  !n     Refer to command line n.
  ```
- Word Designators

  ```
  $      The  last word.  This is usually the last argument, but will 
         expand to the zeroth word if there is only one word in the line.
  ```

So, `!$` just repeats the last word from previous command

Example:

```
$ echo Unix and Linux
Unix and Linux
$ echo !$
echo Linux
Linux
```

```
$ cat dir1
cat: dir1: Is a directory
$ cd !$
cd dir1
```

After executing command with `!$`, press <kbd>↑</kbd> and you will get the result of `!$`.

Comment: Oh! I found the question is duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88642/what-does-mean (flagged to close)